# TraceId is lost in graphql GraphQLAsyncExceptionHandler onException logs

Tags: micronaut, newrelic, javaagents

I have the graphql fetcher as below:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.newrelic.api.agent.NewRelic;
import com.newrelic.api.agent.Token;
import com.newrelic.api.agent.Trace;
import com.newrelic.api.agent.Transaction;
import graphql.execution.DataFetcherResult;
import graphql.schema.DataFetchingEnvironment;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import javax.inject.Singleton;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Singleton
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Mutation1Fetcher
    implements GraphQLDataFetcher<CompletableFuture<DataFetcherResult<SomePojo>> {
  private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

  @Override
  public String getTypeName() {
    return "Mutation";
  }

  @Override
  public String getFieldName() {
    return "mutation1";
  }

  @Override
  @Trace(dispatcher = true)
  public CompletableFuture<DataFetcherResult<SomePojo>> get(DataFetchingEnvironment env)
      throws Exception {
    NewRelic.setTransactionName(null, getTypeName() + "/" + getFieldName());
    UserContext userContext = userContextFactory.createContextWithWritePermissions(env);
    Transaction txn = NewRelic.getAgent().getTransaction();
    log.info("test log 1"); // <- log line 1
    SomeDto dto = objectMapper.convertValue(env.getArgument("content"), SomeDto.class); // this line throws exception
    // ..more code
  }
}
```

Then I have exception handler, as below:

```java
import graphql.execution.DataFetcherExceptionHandler;
import graphql.execution.DataFetcherExceptionHandlerParameters;
import graphql.execution.DataFetcherExceptionHandlerResult;
import jakarta.inject.Singleton;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
@Singleton
public class GraphQLAsyncExceptionHandler implements DataFetcherExceptionHandler {

  @Override
  public DataFetcherExceptionHandlerResult onException(
      DataFetcherExceptionHandlerParameters handlerParameters) {
    log.info("log line 2");
  }
}
```

The `log line 1` has traceId logged in new relic's logs, but `log line 2` looses the traceId, and it doesn't have one.

I have tried adding `txn.getToken().link()` or `txn.getToken().linkAndExpire()` before `objectMapper.convertValue(..` (line which throws an exception), nothing seem to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Also the log 2 may be error, that doesn't work too.

I am using micronaut with new-relic's java agent.

Answer (score 1):

Running `token.link()` is meant to link a transaction with the transaction that generated the token (more info on the [Async API](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/agents/java-agent/async-instrumentation/java-agent-api-asynchronous-applications/#tokens)). So when you run `txn.getToken().link()` you are linking a transaction to itself.

The usual way to use a token is to pass it to the object that will perform asynchronous work during its construction, and then link when it is invoked in another thread. For instance:

```
public class RunnableWithToken implements Runnable {
  private Token token;

  public RunnableWithToken(Token token) {
    this.token = token;
  }

  @Trace(async = true)
  public void run() {
    token.linkAndExpire();
    // do work
  }
}
```

Now, it would be hard to use that strategy in `GraphQLAsyncExceptionHandler` because it is a singleton. And it would not be trivial (if possible at all) to change the exception handling with application code.

This may be worth an improvement request for the Java agent.